# Nullpointer on standalone .jar org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory

Tags: cxf, wsdl2java, micronaut

I have a grpc's micronaut project and I have a gradle task to generate java classes from a wsdl.
The build is success but when I launch the grpc server and call a method that uses one of the generated classes I get the following **error**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:129)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:99)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
    plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.5"
    id "java"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.21"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.21"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.2"
    id "application"
    id "no.nils.wsdl2java" version "0.10"
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.8"
    id "groovy"
    id "jacoco"
}

version "1.0.0"
group "com.myproject"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:1.1.4'
    }
}

configurations {
    // for dependencies that are needed for development only
    developmentOnly
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    compile "io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
    runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    compile "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.0.Final"
    annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.0.Final"
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-bindings-soap', version: '3.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws', version: '3.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http', version: '3.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-ws-security', version: '3.1.11'
    testCompileOnly platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-spock"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.5.0"

}

test.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly

mainClassName = "com.myproject.Application"

ext {
    protocVersion="3.5.1"
    grpcVersion="1.18.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protocVersion}" }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins { grpc {} }
    }
}

// use JUnit 5 platform
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs.add('-parameters')
}


shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

wsdl2java{
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ['-exsh', 'true','-p','com.myproject',
             '-autoNameResolution',
             "-b", "$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/bindings.xml",
             "$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/v1_1.wsdl"]
    ]
    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl")
    locale = Locale.getDefault()
}

wsdl2javaExt {
    cxfVersion = "3.3.2"
}

run.classpath += configurations.developmentOnly
run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs.add('-parameters')
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        html {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.from = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['**/Application*',
                                        'com/myproject/**'])
        })
    }

}

task buildWithCoverage {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'cleanTest'
    dependsOn 'test'
    dependsOn 'jacocoTestReport'
    tasks.findByName('cleanTest').mustRunAfter 'clean'
    tasks.findByName('test').mustRunAfter 'cleanTest'
    tasks.findByName('jacocoTestReport').mustRunAfter 'test'
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not shown where the NPE actually happens. Can you share a sample project or put a breakpoint to that line to find it out?